How can I place marginal distribution on the left side with ggMarginal?
I am learning to plot margial distribution with ggEtra. From the linked website, I can plot it on the right as below:
# library
library(ggplot2)
library(ggExtra)
 
# The mtcars dataset is proposed in R
head(mtcars)
 
# classic plot :
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, color=cyl, size=cyl)) +
      geom_point() +
      theme(legend.position="none")
 
# marginal density
p2 <- ggMarginal(p, type="density", margins="y")

, giving me below figure:

But, I want to know how to plot it on the "left" side. My goal is like this:

Also, as above, I want to place y-axis label between main plot and the marginal plot.
I would be grateful if anyone advise me on how to do this.

In the docs I haven't found an option to place the marginal density plot on the left.
But an easy option to achieve your desired result would be to create your marginal plot as a separate plot and add it to the left of your main plot using patchwork:
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = wt, y = mpg, color = cyl, size = cyl)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

p_density <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(y = mpg)) +
  geom_density() +
  theme_void() +
  scale_x_reverse()

p_density + p + 
  plot_layout(widths = c(1, 4))


